# Is my little proof of lub axiom using (lub axiom in any way)?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

**Below is my little proof of lub axiom**

---

**DEFINITIONS :**

$A$ be any non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ bounded above

$B$ be the set of all real upper bounds of $A$

$x \in B\ \Leftrightarrow \forall\ a \in A, a \leq x$

$B^{*}$ be the set of all reals which are not real upper bounds of $A$

$x \in B^{*}\ \Leftrightarrow \exists \ a \in A, a > x$

---

**LEMMA 1 :** $x \in B^{*} \implies \bigg[ \forall x' < x, x' \in B^{*} \bigg]$

**Proof :** (easy)

**LEMMA 2 :** $x \in B \implies \bigg[ \forall x' > x, x' \in B \bigg]$

**Proof :** (easy)

**LEMMA 3 :** $\exists\ \xi \in \mathbb{R}, \bigg[ (\forall\ x > \xi, x \in B)   ⊻    (\forall\ x < \xi, x \in B^{*}) \bigg]$

**Proof :**

> Choose any $x_1 \in B^{*}$ and any $x_2 \in B$
>
> Consider closed interval $[x_1,x_2]$
>
> Obviously, $\forall\ x \in [x_1,x_2], \bigg[\ (x \in B^{*})  ⊻   (x \in B)\   \bigg]$
>
> **Create a function $f:[x_1,x_2] \to \{0,1\}$ giving $0$ output to $x \in B^{*}$ and $1$ output to $x \in B$**
>
> Obviously, $x_1$ has output $0$ and $x_2$ has output $1$
>
> By **$\Huge\text{Theorem @}$** on continuous functions, there is discontinuity in $f:[x_1,x_2] \to \{0,1\}$

> **By (LEMMA 1) and (LEMMA 2)**,
>
> There is one and only one discontinuity in $f:[x_1,x_2] \to \{0,1\}$, say at $\xi \in [x_1,x_2]$
>
> s̲i̲n̲c̲e̲ ̲m̲o̲r̲e̲ ̲t̲h̲a̲n̲ ̲o̲n̲e̲ ̲d̲i̲s̲c̲o̲n̲t̲i̲n̲u̲i̲t̲y̲ ̲v̲i̲o̲l̲a̲t̲e̲s̲ ̲(̲L̲E̲M̲M̲A̲ ̲1̲)̲ ̲a̲n̲d̲ ̲(̲L̲E̲M̲M̲A̲ ̲2̲)̲
>
> $$\text{}$$
> $$\text{AND}$$
> $$\text{in closed interval $[x_1,x_2]$; the following three statements are true :}$$
> $$\text{}$$
>
> $\forall\ x < \xi, x \in B^{*} \tag1$
>
> s̲i̲n̲c̲e̲ $x < \xi$ ̲m̲u̲s̲t̲ ̲h̲a̲v̲e̲ ̲o̲u̲t̲p̲u̲t̲ $0$, e̲l̲s̲e̲ ̲(̲L̲E̲M̲M̲A̲ ̲1̲)̲ ̲a̲n̲d̲ ̲(̲L̲E̲M̲M̲A̲ ̲2̲)̲ ̲g̲e̲t̲s̲ ̲v̲i̲o̲l̲a̲t̲e̲d̲
>
> $\forall\ x > \xi, x \in B \tag2$
>
> s̲i̲n̲c̲e̲ ̲$x > \xi$ m̲u̲s̲t̲ ̲h̲a̲v̲e̲ ̲o̲u̲t̲p̲u̲t̲ $1$, e̲l̲s̲e̲ ̲(̲L̲E̲M̲M̲A̲ ̲1̲)̲ ̲a̲n̲d̲ ̲(̲L̲E̲M̲M̲A̲ ̲2̲)̲ ̲g̲e̲t̲s̲ ̲v̲i̲o̲l̲a̲t̲e̲d̲
>
> $(\xi \in B^{*})  ⊻   (\xi \in B) \tag3$
>
> s̲i̲n̲c̲e̲ $\xi$ ̲h̲a̲s̲ ̲o̲u̲t̲p̲u̲t̲ ̲e̲i̲t̲h̲e̲r̲ $0$ ̲o̲r̲ $1$

> Thus:
>
> $\exists\ \xi \in \mathbb{R}, \bigg[ (\forall\ x > \xi, x \in B)   ⊻    (\forall\ x < \xi, x \in B^{*}) \bigg]$

**LEMMA 4 :**
$\xi \in B$

**Proof :** (easy)

**Theorem (lub axiom) :**
$\xi$ is lub $A$

---

**$\Huge\text{Questions}$**

$(1)$ Does **Theorem @** use lub axiom in any way ?

$(2)$ In my entire **proof**, am I using lub axiom in any way ?

$(3)$ Is the **proof** perfectly correct ?

Answer (score -1):

The "Theorem" must use the LUB axiom because the theorem is false on the rationals.   Define a function $ f $ on the rationals with $ f(r) = 0 $ if $ r^2 < 2 $ and $f(r)=1$ otherwise.  $ f $ is continuous as a function on $ \mathbb{Q} $.

Comment: Sir, in the case of rationals, certain points from the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ has been taken out of consideration..... The discontinuity, which is apparent, is at a point which has been taken out of consideration....... Is there no other way in which this apparent discontinuity in reals can be proved without using lub property ?

Comment: What axioms are you using for the reals? I think you will find that all other axioms of the reals, besides lub, are true in the rationals.

Comment: Sorry for late reply...... I can see we can prove Theorem @ by considering all possible distributions of 0,1 on interval $[x_1,x_2]$ and ruling out all everywhere continuous cases......  I will definitely try to provide my proof of Theorem @ in another MSE question...... so that those interested and capable in helping me may find out the inaccuracies in my simple proof of that......